# Combine different headers in PHP for non-English text

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, content-type

I am using PHP to display some foreign languages text.

```
  echo '<li> NO ENGLISH </li>';
```

to display a non English language that written in PHP I use:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1255');
```

But when I getting an posted variables from a form and try to echo them, it display trash.
I noticed that setting the next header, fix it :

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

This header display it correctly, but fails display it for the first example.

How can I combine those different header settings in the same file.?

Comment: Either you can use Charset A or you can use Charset B, cant use both Charset headers together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix encodings in a single document. The entire document must be in one coherent encoding with exactly one header set which denotes this encoding. If you receive differently encoded strings from several sources, convert them to one uniform encoding (preferably UTF-8) using [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding) or [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).

If your `'<li> NO ENGLISH </li>'` is simply hardcoded text saved in your source code file, save the file in a different encoding in your text editor. See [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) and [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).

Comment: Thank you, I removed all the headers and simply saved it in UTF-8.